# what is the Command To uninstall all that i have installed in react js using Node js command prompt

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-redux, babel-loader

I just installed react, babel, web pack and redux in nodeJS command prompt and now I want to uninstall all these and wanna begin from starting. how can I do this? and what is the command to run after installing all

Answer (score 2):

Removing a local package from your node_modules directory.

To remove a package from your node_modules directory, on the command line, use the uninstall command. Include the scope if the package is scoped.

Unscoped package

`npm uninstall package_name`

Scoped package

`npm uninstall @scope/package_name`

To remove a package from the dependencies in package.json, use the --save flag. Include the scope if the package is scoped.

`npm uninstall --save package_name`

if it is scoped then

`npm uninstall --save @scope/package_name`

hope this helps...:)